# Clearing Cache in DocumentDB | Managing Ram Usage in AWS DocumentDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ram, aws-documentdb

Is it possible to clear the cache in DocumentDB of AWS?
I tried using the mongoShell using the db.gainlosses.getPlanCache().clear() command but I'm getting this as a result:
MongoServerError: Feature not supported: planCacheClear
so DocuemntDB doesn't support it like many other operations...
I'm having trouble with Memory Usage the server's memory is filled and make it crash....
A serious issue.
I am also getting the FreeableMemory metrics of the documentdb cluster from cloudwatch but I cannot manage it because it is not in real-time...

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing the cache by rebooting the instance, or changing the instance type. But, currently there's no api call to clear the cache in Amazon DocumentDB.